# Simple C transpiler

Tags: c, regex, perl, language-design

I wrote a simple transpiler (that may be a bit of a stretch) in perl to cut down on some boiler plate code.
I'm very new to perl, this being maybe my third ever project in it. My main question would be to ask for feedback on my regular expressions and making it more open to expansion (adding error messages, etc).

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$/ = undef;
while(<>) {
    print "#include <SDL2/SDL.h>\n#include <stdint.h>\n\n";
    s/.include ([^;]+);/#include "\1"/g;
    s/^include ([^;]+);/#include <\1>/g;
    s/entry:/int main(void) {/g;
    s/entry ([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*,\s*([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*:/int main(int \1, char* \2\[\]) {\n\tSDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:u(8|16|32|64)(\**)/uint\2_t\3 \1/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:(8|16|32|64)(\**)/int\2_t\3 \1/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Color\s+({[^}]+})/struct { uint8_t r, g, b, a; }\1 = \2/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Color/struct\s+{ uint8_t r, g, b, a; }\1;/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:-([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/struct \2 \1/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Win\s*{([^}]+)}/SDL_Window* \1 = SDL_CreateWindow(\2)/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Win/SDL_Window* \1/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Ren\s*{([^}]+)}/SDL_Renderer* \1 = SDL_CreateRenderer(\2)/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Ren/SDL_Renderer* \1/g;
    s/@([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*\(([^)]+)\)/typedef struct \1 {\2} \1;/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:@@\s*\(([^)]+)\)/struct {\2}\1;/g;
    s/@/struct /g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:([A-z][A-z0-9]*) ({[^}]*})/\2 \1 = \3/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/\2 \1/g;
    s/Wait\s+a\s+minute!!!/SDL_Delay(60*1000);/g;
    s/wait\s+([0-9bx]+)/SDL_Delay(\1)/g;
    s/clear\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/SDL_RenderClear(\1)/g;
    s/set\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+color\s+to\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(\1, \2.r, \2.g, \2.b, \2.a)/g;
    s/set\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+to\s+([A-z0-9*\/+-]+)/\1.\2 = \3/g;
    s/show\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/SDL_RenderPresent(\1)/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s([A-z][A-z0-9]*\**)\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*:/void \1(\2 \3) {/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*:/void \1(void) {/g;
    s/-!-/}/g;
    print;
}

print "\n";
```

Sample input:

```c
q :@@(
    a :u8;
)

@pixel (
    r :u8; g :u8; b :u8; a :u8;
)

huh a :u8*:

-!-

letmecheck this :pixel:
-!-

entry:
    p :pixel {0, 255, 0, 255};
    win :Win {"Hello world!", 300, 300, 600, 600, 0};
    ren :Ren {win, -1, 0};
    set p g to 127;
    set ren color to p;
    clear ren;
    show ren;
    wait 500;
    set p b to 127;
    set ren color to p;
    clear ren;
    show ren;
    wait 500;
    set p r to 127;
    set ren color to p;
    clear ren;
    show ren;
    wait 500;
-!-
```

output:

```c
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct {
    uint8_t a;
}q;

typedef struct pixel {
    uint8_t r; uint8_t g; uint8_t b; uint8_t a;
} pixel;

void huh(uint8_t* a) {

}

void letmecheck(pixel this) {
}

int main(void) {
    pixel p = {0, 255, 0, 255};
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello world!", 300, 300, 600, 600, 0);
    SDL_Renderer* ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, 0);
    p.g = 127;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, p.r, p.g, p.b, p.a);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    SDL_Delay(500);
    p.b = 127;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, p.r, p.g, p.b, p.a);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    SDL_Delay(500);
    p.r = 127;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, p.r, p.g, p.b, p.a);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    SDL_Delay(500);
}
```

I am open to any and all feedback, thanks in advance!

**EDIT: This is asking for a review of the PERL code, not the C code**

Comment: It's a good idea, but a not so good implementation. You should take a look at compiler construction. Regexes will greatly limit you in speed and development efficiency; You should use a lexer and parser instead. A side note: I like your regexes :)

Comment: Not mentioned by answers: You have a bug. `A-z` should be `A-Za-z`. These are not equivalent.

Answer (score 11):

### Making shebang line more portable

Fixing the `perl` binary to `/usr/bin/perl` in the shebang will not work if you are using `perlbrew` instead of the system `perl`. Using `/usr/bin/env perl` will be a more portable alternative.

### use `strict` and `warnings` pragmas to catch error at an early stage

By adding `warnings` you will get quite a few warnings, as discussed below.

### Unescaped left brace in a regex is deprecated and will be illegal from perl version 5.32 on

You have two lines (line 11 and 21) where you have used a literal `{` in your regex without escaping it. The warning you will get is:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated here (and will be fatal in Perl 5.32), passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:([A-z][A-z0-9]*) ({ <-- HERE [^}]*})/
```

### Unrecognized escape `\s` used in substitution text

On line 12 you have a `\s` in the substitution text. This is not a valid escape in a text string (it is only valid in the regex part of the substitution operator).

```
Unrecognized escape \s passed through at ./p.pl line 12.
```

You can replace `\s+` with a single space for example.

### \1 better written as $1

Replace all uses of the back references `\1`, `\2`, `\3` with `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, see [perldoc perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241) for the details behind this warning.

### Use `say` instead of `print` to avoid having to type `\n` at the end of a string.

Since perl version 5.10 you can add `use feature qw(say)` to your program to use this feature.

### use `local` to avoid clobbering special (global) variables

Even if it is not necessary in your short program, you should localize `$/` when you set it to `undef`: This will avoid bugs from creeping in at a later time when your program grows larger. If you do not localize the variable it will be set globally for your whole program to `undef`.

### Use dedicated parsing modules to simplify maintenance and readability of your code

Your code is already starting to become hard to read and maintain (due to the complicated syntax of the regexes). Consider using a dedicated grammar and a parser like [`Regexp::Grammars`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars) to make your program readable and easier to maintain.

Here is a modified version of your code incorporating some of the changes suggested above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = undef;
while(<>) {
    say "#include <SDL2/SDL.h>\n#include <stdint.h>\n";
    s/.include ([^;]+);/#include "$1"/g;
    s/^include ([^;]+);/#include <$1>/g;
    s/entry:/int main(void) {/g;
    s/entry ([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*,\s*([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*:/int main(int $1, char* $2\[\]) {\n\tSDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:u(8|16|32|64)(\**)/uint$2_t$3 $1/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:(8|16|32|64)(\**)/int$2_t$3 $1/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Color\s+(\{[^}]+\})/struct { uint8_t r, g, b, a; }$1 = $2/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Color/struct { uint8_t r, g, b, a; }$1;/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:-([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/struct $2 $1/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Win\s*{([^}]+)}/SDL_Window* $1 = SDL_CreateWindow($2)/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Win/SDL_Window* $1/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Ren\s*{([^}]+)}/SDL_Renderer* $1 = SDL_CreateRenderer($2)/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:Ren/SDL_Renderer* $1/g;
    s/@([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*\(([^)]+)\)/typedef struct $1 {$2} $1;/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:@@\s*\(([^)]+)\)/struct {$2}$1;/g;
    s/@/struct /g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:([A-z][A-z0-9]*) (\{[^}]*\})/$2 $1 = $3/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/$2 $1/g;
    s/Wait\s+a\s+minute!!!/SDL_Delay(60*1000);/g;
    s/wait\s+([0-9bx]+)/SDL_Delay($1)/g;
    s/clear\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/SDL_RenderClear($1)/g;
    s/set\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+color\s+to\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/SDL_SetRenderDrawColor($1, $2.r, $2.g, $2.b, $2.a)/g;
    s/set\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+to\s+([A-z0-9*\/+-]+)/$1.$2 = $3/g;
    s/show\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)/SDL_RenderPresent($1)/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s([A-z][A-z0-9]*\**)\s+([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*:/void $1($2 $3) {/g;
    s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*:/void $1(void) {/g;
    s/-!-/}/g;
    print;
}

say "";
```

Answer (score 7):

Along with the excellent answer of [Håkon Hægland](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/243631/225887),

Use perl's quoted regexes to simplify your code and improve readability massively.

```
my $keyword = qr/[A-z][A-z0-9]*/; 
my $bits = qr/(?:8|16|32|64)/;
```

Makes:

```
s/entry ([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*,\s*([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s*:/int main(int \1, char* \2\[\]) {\n\tSDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);/g;
s/([A-z][A-z0-9]*)\s+:u(8|16|32|64)(\**)/uint\2_t\3 \1/g;
```

into

```
s/entry ($keyword)\s*,\s*($keyword)\s*:/int main(int \1, char* \2\[\]) {\n\tSDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);/g;
s/($keyword)\s+:u($bits)(\**)/uint\2_t\3 \1/g;
```

Answer (score 4):

> open to expansion

**Avoid naked undocumented numbers**

Code has  `SDL_Delay(500);` 3 times.  Are the values related?  500 what?

Since it is likely the values are to change in common, create code the reflects that.  This makes for easier to expand/maintain code.

```
#define VIEWING_PAUSE (500 /* ms */)

// SDL_Delay(500);
SDL_Delay(VIEWING_PAUSE);
```

Likewise for 127, 300, 600 .... as maybe `HALF_RED, WIDTH, HEIGHT`

> I am open to any and all feedback

**Minor: keywords**

When forming C code, even though not required, recommend to avoid C++ keywords like `this`.  (`delete`, `new`, `class`, ....)

```
// void letmecheck(pixel this) {
void letmecheck(pixel this_pixel) {
```

Comment: I think I need to adjust the question in some way. I was actually asking for advice on the perl code that outputs the C code that you responded too. Sorry about that

Comment: @Shipof123 My thoughts here are meant to imply a change to the perl code to effect the suggested changes in C.

Comment: I think that adding definitions into the perl output could cause collisions, that being said, adding comments into the output code that reflect the input would be useful.

Comment: The repetitions of 500 come from the **input** to the perl code. The transpiler could recognize repeated constants in the input and turn them into a single definition, but that's a feature request and not a code review.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let me mention that if you want to build a production quality, maintainable, and scalable transpiler you should not do it using regular expressions.  That is regardless of the language in which the regular expressions are written, even if perl.  Without going into much detail, regular expressions work on plain text, and you need more than that to do anything non-trivial.   You can look into compiler theory if you want to learn more about that.

For your use, namely converting something you have full control over into something else you also have full control over in a simple line-by-line conversion, and that *only you will use* this is fine.  Others have discussed the quality of your current code, I won't go into that.

I will, however, mention that undocumented regular expressions are *very* hard to maintain.  You should at least document each well - Perl has a verbose form well suited for this.  You should have test cases that ensures that if you put in a known source file, you get exactly what you expect out in the other end.  If not, something broke.

You may also want to consider peer review.  Have a colleague or fellow student to look at your code and listen to what baffles them.  If it confuses them now, it will confuse you too later when you have forgotten the tiny details, which happens to each and every programmer at some point, and THAT is when important projects get rewritten.  At the current state you will probably have a hard time convincing anybody to inherit maintainership of your code.

Good luck - this is a very good exercise.